# playframework scala - cannot find controllers.Application

Tags: scala, playframework

As a test project to try out scala I've installed Play framework with the Scala module, following the instructions provided here:

http://scala.playframework.org/

The project gets created fine, but when I go to the home url I get a warning saying the server cannot find the default controller. I've not modified anything from the default install at this point, so my controller looks like this:

```
package controllers

import play._
import play.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

    def index = Template

}
```

Any ideas on what am I missing?

Comment: check with any working scala sample the differences, that may help

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are called action generators. By default the template name will be resolved from the action method name. So if the controllers.Application.index method returns a Template, the app/views/Application/index.html template will be rendered.

Also try cleaning up and re-running the app, sometime it escapes the file updates.

Have a look here http://www.playframework.org/modules/scala-0.9/controllers